# Transferring German permanent residence permit (Daueraufenthalt-EU) to new passport - documents / proof needed

Tags: germany, resident-permit, residency

I'm currently employed and living in Germany. I have a Daueraufenthalt-EU card, whose validity ("kartennutzung bis DDMM2024") is tied to my US passport which expires in 2024.

What documents or proof are needed when a new card needs to be issued against the new passport?

I am exploring the possibility of a sabbatical or early retirement, which means I will not be able to show any payslips or letter from the employer. However, my residence will remain in Germany and I will cover my living expenses as well as my German private health insurance.

Comment: My guess is that you simply have to make an appointment, show your new passport and sign somewhere. Then you hand in your old card, when your new one is ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an income requirement (§ 9a AufenthG: “*feste und regelmäßige Einkünfte*”) but you don't need a job *per se*. The [berlin.de website](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/324281/) mentions freelancers (rather then early retirement) but many types of evidence of income are acceptable. Some of those are very generic (bank statements, *Steuerbescheide*). At the same time, the form is strongly geared towards people who have some sort of economic activity and what's required is a regular *income*. It might not be enough to be moderately wealthy and claim that's enough to cover your needs, you need to show money “flowing into your account”.

You've got insurance covered and since this is a renewal I assume you also fulfil all the other requirements (residence, knowledge of the language, no criminal conviction, etc.)

Disclaimer: I don't have any first-hand experience with this particular procedure.

Comment: thank you for the useful information. Yes, the other requirements (residence, etc) would be fulfilled. There are numerous resources geared towards new permanent residence applications but hardly any resources or postings related to obtaining a new card once a passport has to be renewed. This [berlin.de page](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/121874/en/) covers residence permit transfers (unsure if it applies to limited, permanent, or both) but it appears to require only the old and new passports, existing card, and a new photo.

Comment: @dbninva [This page](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/324280/en/) covers permanent residence permits. If that's the right procedure, your source of income wouldn't come up. Thinking about it, it makes sense: What you have is a permanent residence right (*unbefristet*), it doesn't need to be renewed, it's only the card that needs to be replaced. That's also probably why it says “*Kartennutzung bis*” and not "*gültig bis*".

Comment: Very nice - thanks for the page! It is the most relevant resource I've come across. Appreciate it.

Comment: The stated requirements in this answer are for getting the permit in the first place not for getting a new card.

Comment: @life-on-mars Yeah, we discussed that in the comments above, will see if I can clarify the answer.